# pgAdmin version 4-5.3 where is the geometry viewer

Tags: pgadmin-4

Updated the pgAdmin to latest version 4-5.3 on Windows 64 bit, I can not find the geometry-viewer anymore.
So howto "activate" the geometry-viewer in the latest version?

**Update:**
As @JGH shows in the answer the button for the geometry-viewer is very FAR right, you have to scroll a LOT to reach the geometry-viewer-button. Before version 4-5.3, the columns-width by default was small. You can change this by setting the following preference:
[image]

Voila, now you have the same "design" like in older versions of pgAdmin

Comment: Rather than commenting on an Answer in your Question, adding your own Answer with an addendum might better match the Q&A model used here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to the far right of the geometry column and click on the eye icon

[image]

==>

[image]